# Javascript equals "0" returning true

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain this behavior:

```
"2"=="3"=="4"=="5"
>false
"2"=="3"=="4"=="0"
>true
```

Just noticed it in console, I would expect both statements to be false. I notice that the `true` return seems to be an issue when only the LAST value is `"0"`. It's a string comparison though so I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: I think it's doing false=="0" == true

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript just with some more evaluation left-to-right

Comment: That's because `false == false` is true.

Comment: and thats why we need to use ===

Comment: A great reason never to use the `==` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one eventually evaluates to `false == "0"`. Since Since 0 is falsey, this evaluates to `true`.

```js
console.log(false == "0");
```

Comment: console.log(Boolean("0")== Boolean(0)),  return false. Why?

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript evaluates left-to-right.

Your equations are essentially `(("2"=="3")=="4")=="5"` and `(("2"=="3")=="4")=="0"`.

Breaking down equation #1:

```
"2" == "3" // false
false == "4" // false
false == "5" // false
```

Thus the first equation evaluates to `false`.

Breaking down equation #2:

```
"2" == "3" // false
false == "4" // false
false == "0" // true
```

Thus the second equation evaluates to `true`. This is due to [truthiness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) equating `"0"` as `false`.

If you were to use `===` (checking for [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity)), the second equation would evaluate to `true`.

Comment: _Some_ JS operators evaluate left-to-right, and `==` is one of them. Others evaluate right-to-left.

Answer (score 0):

```
step1: "2"=="3"=="4"=="5"
step2: false=="4"=="5"
step3: false=="5"
step4: false

step1: "2"=="3"=="4"=="0"
step2: false=="4"=="0"
step3: false=="0"
step4: true
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript always evaluates expressions from  left to right order. 
For expression a=b+c/d  a is evaluated and then b,c,d

```js
console.log("2"=="3"=="4"=="5"); //false
 /* 
    1. First it will evaluate "2"=="3" as false 
    2. false=="4"=="5" Then it will evaluate false=="4" as false
    3. then false=="5" is false again 
 */
console.log("2"=="3"=="4"=="0"); //true
/* 
    1. First it will evaluate 2==3 as false 
    2. false=="4"=="0" Then it will evaluate false=="4" as false
    3. then false=="0" is true , because 0 is false 
 */
```

Comment: _"JavaScript always evaluates expressions from left to right order."_ Incorrect. It evaluatates some operators left-to-right and others right-to-left.

Comment: @JLRishe : Never knew that, can you please share some examples

Comment: You can have a look at this [operator precedence table](http://www-lia.deis.unibo.it/materiale/JS/developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence.html). By necessity, the unary and assignment operators are right-to-left. In `a = b = c = 4 + 5`, first `4 + 5` is evaluated to 9, then `c = 9`, `b = 9`, `a = 9`, in that order. Also, something like `-~!true` would be evaluated `!true` -> `false`, `~false` -> ``-1`, `-(-1)` -> `1`.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript false evaluates to 0 i:e zero.

So when you do "2"=="3" the answer is 0

0=="4" again is false i:e 0

0=="5" again evaluates to false. Hence the Answer to "2"=="3"=="4"=="5" is false.

And in your second statement "2"=="3"=="4"=="0"
"2"=="3"=="4" evaluates to false.

And false == 0 evaluates to true. 
Hence the answer of "2"=="3"=="4"=="0" is false=="0" i:e true.

Hope that explanation helps.

Have a good day !

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Because this case "==" compare number values instead of boolean values
> Step 1 : "2"=="3" //"2" == "3" ? Return false
> Step 2 : Number(false)==Number("4") //0 == 4 ? Return false
> Step 3 : Number(false)==Number("0") //0 == 0 ? Return true
>
> try this: console.log("A"=="A"==1)
> Step 1 : "A"=="A" //"A" == "A" ? Return True
> Step 2 : Number(true) == 1  // 1 == 1 ? Return true;
> ```